# _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Widget')

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Basit ToDo Uygulaması",
      home: Iskele(),
    );
  }
}

class Iskele extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ToDo Uygulaması"),
      ),
      body: AnaEkran(),
    );
  }
}

class AnaEkran extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnaEkranState createState() => _AnaEkranState();
}

class _AnaEkranState extends State<AnaEkran> {
  TextEditingController t1 = TextEditingController();
  List alisverisListesi = [];

  elemanEkle() {
    setState(() {
      alisverisListesi.add(t1.text);
      t1.clear();
    });
  }

  elemanCikar() {
    setState(() {
      alisverisListesi.remove(t1.text);
      t1.clear();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: alisverisListesi.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, siraNumarasi) => ListTile(
                subtitle: Text("Marketten Alınacaklar"),
                title: Text(alisverisListesi[siraNumarasi]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: t1,
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: elemanEkle,
            child: Text("Ekle"),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: elemanCikar,
            child: Text("Çıkar"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  
  RaisedButton({required Function() onPressed, required Text child}) {}
}
```

**

> main.dart

**
*!!*
I don't understand why I'm getting this error, can you help me? I am
trying to make a simple app in Flutter but I have this error in front
of me.
I don't understand why I'm getting this error, can you help me? I am
trying to make a simple app in Flutter but I have this error in front
of me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove line 82: `RaisedButton({required Function() onPressed, required Text child}) {}`. I don't actually understand what this line is supposed to do, can you explain that?

I do know why this caused an issue though. This is interpreted as a function without a return type. This causes the return type to be dynamic, essentially disabling dart's typesystem. That is why the compiler doesn't complain. Then this function returns null and throws this error.

Another thing, RaisedButton is depricated. Please don't use it. Use ElevatedButton instead.